# How to handle wait during a datadriven test using testNG in a webdriver script

Tags: webdriver, testng, data-driven-tests

This is my scenario, i use webdriver with testNG for doing data driven test. I am observing that the data i am 'seeing' in web app which is provided by @dataprovider is missing some value. For exg if i have an array as {"1","2","3","4","5"}, i am getting these value in webdriver script using testNG @dataprovider, i am observing in the 'Web GUI' initially 2 might be displayed, then in the next iteration 5 is displayed then the test stop.

I am assuming that TestNG is not waiting for webdriver to complete the function or process.

Here is  my sample code

```
@Test (dataProviderClass=MyDataProviders.class)
public class MyWebDriverClass{

        @Test(dataProvider = "theProviderName")
    public void providerHomeCreateuser(String arg1,String arg2)
            {
               <..input arg1, arg2 to text fields..>
            }
}
```

I understand somewhere i need to put a Thread.wait(), could any body guide me on this.

Data provider method is as follows

```
public class MyDataProviders {
...
...

    @DataProvider (name="theProviderName")
        public static Object[][] getData() throws Exception
        {
            Object retObject[][]=getTableArray("src\\com\\abcd\\resource\\TestData.xls", 5, "MyTestData");
            return retObject;       
        }
```

Comment: 1. What is your dataprovider logic like?
2. What multithreading options are on for your testing?

Comment: Dataprovider returns an Object[][] form an excel file. I am not sure  about multithreading, i am not initializing any Thread class.

Comment: Data provider logic updated in question

Comment: @patrungel, Thank you very much , my application extensively use AJAX application, at times, it is needed to provide Thread.sleep() to make testNG to slow down till the web application complete certain validations.

Comment: what do you see when you println for arg1 and arg2?